# Default condition not working in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I have below code:

```
var port = request.app.settings.port || 3000;
```

This throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
   at forceLogin (/home/projects/nodejs/node_modules/connect-keycloak/middleware/protect.js:5:25)
   at /home/jaec/WebstormProjects/punters/services-api/node_modules/connect-keycloak/middleware/protect.js:44:5
   at call (/home/jaec/WebstormProjects/punters/services-api/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:210:7)
   at next (/home/jaec/WebstormProjects/punters/services-api/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:154:5)
   at Function.app.handle (/home/jaec/WebstormProjects/punters/services-api/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:157:3)
   at Server.app (/home/jaec/WebstormProjects/punters/services-api/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:28:37)
   at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2113:12)
   at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23)
   at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1971:22)
```

Is there a reason why it's not picking up default which is 3000?

Comment: By default `request` has no attribute named `app`.... So unless you added it... I think you made some mistake.

Comment: And if you wanted to check for first option and supply other in case it was not present you should have done this - `var port = ( request.app && request.app.settings && request.app.settings.port ) || 3000;` It will first check for presence of `request.app.settings.port` but assign 3000 if it were not present.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This would have worked:
var port = undefined || 3000;

//this throws an error
var port = undefined.settings || 3000
```

undefined does not have properties

```
var object = { };
object.prop // undefined
object.prop.another // throws an error
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to check if `request.app.settings.port` is defined and assign its value but assign `3000` if it is not defined.

In that case you want to do following,

```
var port = ( request.app && request.app.settings && request.app.settings.port ) || 3000;
```